# Save base64 string as image using phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I am getting a base64 string from the server for a png file and i would like to save this image on the file system. It looks like phonegap filewriter only supports binary. Does anyone know how i can convert this base64 string to use in phonegap. I was looking at window.atob and window.btoa but couldnt make sense of things.

Comment: If its a single file then you can store it in local storage

Comment: my requirement i to save it on the file system

Comment: You may want to check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20419574/saving-dataurlbase64-to-file-on-phonegap-android), it saves dataUrl which is base64 to a png image on android file system

Answer (score 2):

You can not use the PhoneGap FileWriter to write binary data. You'd need to write a plugin to send your base64 encoded data to the native side, encode it into binary then write it using native code.

Check out the plugins info at: [HERE](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36752779/PhoneGap%20Plugins)  also take a look at the phonegap source code to see how we do the file writer and you can add some code to do the base64 decode before writing.

Comment: You can refer this also - http://blog.danguer.com/2011/10/24/base64-binary-decoding-in-javascript/

Comment: I believe you can use the phonegap filewriter to write binary data in IOS and Android. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileWriter

Comment: Refer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388018/phonegap-plugin-to-convert-base64-string-to-a-png-image-in-android

Comment: thanks. FYI writing binary files using filewriter was added in phonegap 2.9

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, phonegap don't provide a way to save an image to the filesystem. You need a phonegap plugin to do that.
[Canvas2Image](https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin) nearly do what you want. It take a canvas id, extract a base64 string from the canvas and save it as an image. You can slightly alter the javascript part of the plugins to accept a base64 string instead of a canvas id.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a good plugin to save BASE64 into filesystem.

[Phonegap Image Resizer](https://github.com/RaananW/PhoneGap-Image-Resizer)

```
window.imageResizer.storeImage(
  function(json) { 
    console.log('Saved to ' + json.url) 
  }, function (error) {
    console.log("Error : \r\n" + error);
  }, imageDataInBase64);
```

More detail see the comment [imageresize.js](https://github.com/RaananW/PhoneGap-Image-Resizer/blob/master/www/imageresize.js#L101)