# Saving the canvas image to device library using phonegap FILE API

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, cross-platform, phonegap-plugins

Is it possible to store the the canvas image to device library using **phonegap** **FILE API**

Comment: [Refer for storage limitations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20419574/saving-dataurlbase64-to-file-on-phonegap-android) and [Refer this for Plugin to convert Base64 to File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388018/phonegap-plugin-to-convert-base64-string-to-a-png-image-in-android) then you continue with [phonegap file plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file)

Comment: will it store the image in photo library?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
// Draw your canvas here
//...
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(); // getting base64 string
```

Once you got the base64 string set up the [phonegap plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388018/phonegap-plugin-to-convert-base64-string-to-a-png-image-in-android) for converting base64 image string  to png or jpg file

the above mentioned plugin automatically store image to */sdcard/Pictures*

```
window.plugins.base64ToPNG.saveImage(myBase64, {filename:"dot.png", overwrite: true},
```